# How can I make my navigation links work from any page?

Tags: python, django, url

I have a Django template containing this menu:

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li class="nav-current" role="presentation"><a href="">index</a></li>
 <li role="presentation"><a href="/cpuinfo/">cpu info</a></li>
 <li role="presentation"><a href="#">about</a></li>
 </ul>
```

When I click "cpu info" from the home page my browser goes to `/cpuinfo`. This works.

But when I am on other pages like `/post/` that link takes me to `/post/cpuinfo`, which isn't correct.

How can I make my link work from any page?

Comment: It's a good idea to use the url tag as Bear Brown suggested, but it's not required. A link `/cpuinfo/` should always take you to `/cpuinfo/`. 

However, if you had `<a href="cpuinfo/">` (without the leading slash), then this is a relative URL, which will take you from `/post/` to `/post/cpuinfo/`.

Answer (score 1):

You need [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url) in template, for example:

```
<li role="presentation"><a href="{% url 'cpuinfo'%}">cpu info</a></li>
                             <!-- Change it ^^^ on real url name-->
```

Comment: from you comments cpuinfo its from other app , i register cpufinfo to current app urls.py. then use {% url 'cpuinfo:cpuinfo '%} now its working thanks alot.